# How do I find if the current executed code is on the UI thread?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight-4.0, autoresetevent

I am developing a silverlight application and I have a method that should throw an exception if it's ran on the UI thread since it uses AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() without timeout which causes the UI thread to freeze.
How do I detect if the current thread is the UI thread?

EDIT:
Note that this method resides in a class library and not in a UI component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if you are in the main UI thread by using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` (use the *CheckAccess()* function).

Notice i said *main UI thread* - this is important, as any thread can have a dispatcher associated with it*, and you can have more than one UI thread. To be more accurate, your question should be

> How do I find if the current executed code is **a** UI thread?

AFAIK this may not be possible with any certainty, as the only real discernable difference (that i have seen) between a background (thread pool) thread and a UI thread is their ApartmentState - UI threads are STA, and the threads available in the thread pool are MTA. This doesn't mean that a STA thread is a UI thread though. *(I would be glad for someone to chip in with something definitive here)*. Maybe your solution is to look at it the other way - ensure that the `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` calls are only done on threads that are MTA.

<sub>*just try executing the code `this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` on a background thread and see what happens....</sub>

### **Edit:**

thanks to @drow for pointing out that this should be Silverlight... duh. I will leave the answer above untouched as it is still applicable for WPF. As mentioned by @drow, there is no way to access the ApartmentState of the thread in Silverlight, and the Dispatcher is not available when using *System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread*.

So as another option you can check whether `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` returns *false*, if it is then you are on a background thread (i.e. not the main UI thread). I did test this, and it works nicely.

Comment: @the_drow, thanks for catching that, I've edited my answer accordingly.